# r gWidgets How to get gcombobox value?

Tags: r

I'm new with making gui's and I need some help.

I have a gcombobox, and i want to know users choice after clicking on button Calculate

```
library(gWidgets)

city <- c("NY", "Tokyo", "Rome")

#main window
window <- gwindow(title = "stackoverflow",
                  visible=TRUE)

group <- ggroup(cont = window)
lay <- glayout(cont=group) 

lay[1,1] <- "City:"
lay[1,2] <- gcombobox(city, 
              selected=0L, 
              cont=lay)

lay[2,2] <- gbutton(text = "Calculate",
            border = TRUE,
            cont = lay,
            handler = function(h,...){

            #here i want to know the users choice(NY, Tokyo, Rome). 
            #for example: if(combobox == "Rome") a = 5


            })
```

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get value of `lay[1,2]`using `svalue`

for example

```
lay[2,2] <- gbutton(text = "Calculate",
                border = TRUE,
                cont = lay,
                handler = function(h,...){
                  combobox=svalue(lay[1,2])
                if(combobox == "Rome")  {
                  a = 5} else {
                    a=0
                  }
                print(paste(combobox , a))
              })
```